# How to get a combined data from previous forms?

Tags: android, forms, sharedpreferences

I have followed [this link](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial)  and I get last saved data but what I want is when one of the EditText is empty it returns the previous full one ; 
For example I posted only the name and saved the form then I posted only the email I want when I return I get both of them , is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You can save each filed individually in Shared Preference and also retrieve them individually at any time.
In case of your example, you can check which fields are non-null and can save those fields data using shared preference.

Comment: the problem in my case that every data will be edited by another activity

Comment: You can save data in shared preference from any activity, just make sure you use the proper key to save a variable.
For example,
use editor.putString("key" , "value"); to add a string value against 'key'

Comment: make sure you access the same shared preference all over your app
sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("name_of_your_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: If it doesn't bother you , can you show me a link to follow

Comment: ohh.. i don't know a link specifically for your problem.
I have used this stuff in my app

Comment: I found it http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/use-getsharedpreferences-to-retrieve.html , thank's you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your question in more detail and with examples?

According to me what i understand you want to save data when state of application is changed. so you are saving data in Shared Preferences.

If you want to save primitive data then Shared Preferences is good place to store.

But if you want to store complex data and want to apply some business use ViewModel class https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

and to have a reactive application use RXJAVA which is very powerfull.

Comment: In my case every edittext open an activity when I return to the form the others disappear and only the last edited one is shown , I don't know if i arrived to explain it well